# Using 'stratify' in train_test_split doesn't make a difference. What is it used for?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was just experimenting with the 'stratified' parameter in sklearn's train_test_split function. My dataset in imbalanced and the following is the proportion of classes:

Class 0: 8,902
Class 1: 1,605

Class 1 makes up 15% of the dataset.

Here is it is the default split without using stratify:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['image'], df['class'], test_size=0.2,random_state=5)

Training set balance:
0    7,116
1    1,289

Test set balance:
0    1,786
1     316
```

and below I use stratify:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['image'], df['class'], test_size=0.2,random_state=5,stratify=df['class'])

Training set balance:
0    7121
1    1284

Test set balance:
0    1781
1     321
```

It's about the same proportion in both: 18% for class 1. Adding 'stratify' didn't do anything.

So this has left me a bit confused. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Strange. Can you shuffle the data and try it once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `stratify` will guarantee the proportion of 1 is the same as in original data.

Calculating the proportion of 1:

**original**:

```
Total:  print(1605/(1605+8902)) = 0.1527553059864852
```

**without `stratify`**:

```
Train:  print(1289/(1289+7116)) = 0.1533610945865556
Test:   print(316/(316+1786)) = 0.15033301617507136
```

As you can see, proportion of 1 is not the same as in original data and when you sample for another time, the proportion might be different! (It is similar because it is random sampling)

**with stratify**:

```
Train:  print(1284/(1284+7121)) = 0.15276621058893516
Test:   print(321/(321+1781)) = 0.1527117031398668
```

The same as in original data, and even sampling for another time, the proportion would not change. So stratify does its job isn't it?